# Show an alternative definition of the infinite norm of a measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

To have a clearer idea I will make the following definition.

Let $ (X,\mathscr{A},\mu) $ a measure space. We define
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_{\infty}=\{f\in (M,\mathscr{A}): f \mbox{ is bounded } (a.e.) \}
\end{equation}
and for $ f\in\mathscr{L}_{\infty} $ we have:
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{\infty}=\inf\{a>0:\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>a\})=0\}.
\end{equation}

What I want is to prove that proposition.

Let $ f\in\|f\|_{\infty}$, then
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup\{c\geq 0:\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq c\})>0\} \mbox{ (alternative definition)}.
\end{equation}

I tried to do this:

Let $b=\sup\{c\geq0:\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq c\})>0\}$. If $b=0\Rightarrow \mbox{for all } c>0$ we have $\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|> c\})=0$, then $\|f\|_{\infty}=0$. Conversely, if $\|f\|_{\infty}=0$, we obtain $|f(x)|\leq\|f\|_{\infty}=0, \ a.e.$ then $f=0, \ a.e. \Rightarrow \ b=0$. Thus $\|f\|_{\infty}=b$.

For the case $\|f\|_{\infty}>0$, I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the other definition?

Comment: The other definition is probably $\inf\{d\ge 0: |f|\le d$ a.e.$\}$. It might be helpful to prove first that this infimum is in fact a minimum (because contable unions of null sets are null sets).

Comment: Isn't this norm generally defined by $\|f\|_\infty = \sup\{|f(x)|: x\in X\}$? The given quantity $\sup\{c\geqslant 0: \mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geqslant c\})>0\}$ is known (to me at least) as the *essential supremum* of a function.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope that now it is clearer what I want to demonstrate. I appreciate any help.